# How to investigate service crash in docker

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run my first Asp.Net core service in docker, it exits immediately, I assume because the process crashes. If it was on VM I know what I would do: look into system Event Viewer, look into exception logs, or try to attach debugger. What are my options with docker?

Comment: will you share your full `docker run` command ?

Answer (score -2):

Run

`docker ps -a`

This will list down all your running and exited containers.

Now run

```
docker inspect <YOUR_STOPPED_CONTAINER_ID>
```

This will list down all the properties of that container (like the exit code and the error, if available)

Edit:

You can use docker logs as well. For all the available options refer [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

```
docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```